# PHP URL for my homepage

Tags: php, url

so I'm editing a PHP site (I'm a Python guy). What I need is a way to maybe redirect such that when someone navigates to the site e.g. `www.mysite.com`, the homepage should be served. The system used to serve other pages is as sush: to navigate let's say to the contacts page, we use `www.mysite.com?page_id=contact-us`. The query string helps the server side code to know what page to serve. So what I want is that when a user navigates to the site by typing `www.mysite.com`, he should get to the page `www.mysite.com?page_id=home`.

Thank you.

Sample code:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page_id']) ? $_GET['page_id'] : null;
    if ($page !== null) {
            //redirect to correct page
        require("modules/inside.php");
    } else {
            //redirect to 'home'
        header('Location: https://www.ndovucard.com?page_id=home');
        require("modules/home.php");
    }
```

Comment: check for page_id. if it is empty then redirect to home page.

Comment: can we see some code from the script that processes the url query?

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
if (!isset($_GET['page_id'])){
   header('Location: www.mysite.com?page_id=home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page_id'])) ? $_GET['page_id'] : 'home';
echo $page; // 'home' or provided page_id
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said it sounds like you need a:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page_id'])) $_GET['page_id'] = 'home';
```

Personally I prefer a full URL rewrite system rather than passed by URL query as it's believed search engines prefer contact-us.html rather than page_id=contact-us

Edit:
You could alternatively do:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    header('Location: /?page_id=home');
    die(); // stop any further processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page_id']) ? $_GET['page_id'] : 'home';
/* check that page is a valid page else serve error page */
/* then redirect to the correct $page */
header('Location: www.mysite.com?page_id=' . $page);
exit();
```

By the way, you need some way to check that `$_GET['page_id']` is always a valid `page_id` before redirecting.

Comment: This is a good idea...thanks. However, I am trying to redirect as such: header('Location: https://www.ndovucard.com?page_id=home'); and it ain't working. What could be the issue?

Comment: What is it defaulting to? Make sure you are getting values from `$_GET['page_id']`.

Comment: Yes I am...URL stays the same

Comment: @Denny You need to describe the behaviour you are getting completely... is it always redirecting to 'home' or it's never getting to 'home'.

Comment: When one types www.mysite.com on the address box, it remains the same...it doesn't redirect to www.mysite.com/?page_id=home. It never gets to 'home'